# Degenerate eigenvectors don't respect the symmetry of the matrix using SciPy or NumPy libraries

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, eigenvector

We are trying to diagonalize the two following matrices: matrix1 and matrix2
We compared our results with Wolfram Mathematica and in the first matrix we obtained different results when comparing eigenvectors corresponding to degenerate eigenvalues.

Here the code we use in python. In Mathematica we just use the classic function "Eigensystem[]".

As you can see for the first matrix the results from SciPy and Mathematica are really different while for the second one the coincide.

In particular what we observe that for the first matrix the 2nd and 3rd eigenvectors are degenerate in energy. In Mathematica "Eigensystem[]" is able to find two eigenvectors that conserve the translational symmetry of the matrix while Python, in this particular case, is not.

Surprisingly for the second matrix the two results, Mathematica and Python, are the same.

Does anyone has some ideas why this is happening and how to solve it?
Our goal would be to diagonalize large sparse hermitian matrices but we also find the same problem in that case.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg
import scipy.linalg

t=-1
matrix1 = np.array([ [0, t, 0, 0, t], [t, 0, t, 0, 0],[0, t, 0, t, 0],[0, 0, t, 0, t],[t, 0, 0, t, 0]])

matrix2 = np.array([[0, t, 0, t, 0],[t, 0, t, 0, t],[0, t, 0, t, 0],[t, 0, t, 0, t],[0, t, 0, t, 0]])

E1,V1   = linalg.eigh(matrix1)
E2,V2 = linalg.eigh(matrix2)

print('.....First Matrix')
print('Matrix')
print(matrix1)
print('Eigenvalues')
print(E1)
print('Eigenvectors')
for i in range(len(V1)):
    print(V1[:,i]

print('')

print('.....Second Matrix')
print('Matrix')
print(matrix2)
print('Eigenvalues')
print(E2)
print('Eigenvectors')
for i in range(len(V2)):
    print(V2[:,i])
```

Here is the output of python and mathematica for the two matrices.

```
......First Matrix..............................................................

.....PYTHON.....

Matrix

[[ 0 -1  0  0 -1]

 [-1  0 -1  0  0]

 [ 0 -1  0 -1  0]

 [ 0  0 -1  0 -1]

 [-1  0  0 -1  0]]

Eigenvalues

[-2.    -0.618 -0.618  1.618  1.618]

Eigenvectors

[-0.447 -0.447 -0.447 -0.447 -0.447]

[ 0.103  0.625  0.283 -0.450 -0.561]

[-0.624 -0.094  0.566  0.444 -0.291]

[ 0.632 -0.512  0.195  0.195 -0.512]

[ 0.000  0.371 -0.601  0.601 -0.371]


.....MATHEMATICA.....

Eigenvalues

(-2.,-0.618034,-0.618034,1.61803,1.61803)

Eigenvectors

(-0.44721   -0.44721  -0.447214 -0.447214   -0.447214

  0.60150    0.37174  -0.371748 -0.601501   0.

  0.19544   -0.51166  -0.511667  0.19544    0.632456

 -0.51166    0.19544   0.19544  -0.511667   0.632456

 -0.37174    0.60150  -0.601501  0.371748   0.)


......Second Matrix..............................................................

.....PYTHON.....

Matrix

[[ 0 -1  0 -1  0]

 [-1  0 -1  0 -1]

 [ 0 -1  0 -1  0]

 [-1  0 -1  0 -1]

 [ 0 -1  0 -1  0]]

Eigenvalues

[-2.449 0  0  0  2.449]

Eigenvectors

[ 0.408  0.5    0.408  0.5    0.408]

[ 0.816  0     -0.408  0     -0.408]

[ 0.    -0.707  0.     0.707  0.   ]

[ 0.     0.    -0.707  0.     0.707]

[-0.408  0.5   -0.408  0.5   -0.408]




.....MATHEMATICA.....

Eigenvalues

(-2.44949,0.,0.,3.55271*10^-15,2.44949)

Eigenvectors

(-0.408248  -0.5    -0.408248   -0.5    -0.408248

0   0.707107    0   -0.707107   0

0.707107    0   -0.707107   0   0

-0.408248   0   -0.408248   0   0.816497

-0.408248   0.5 -0.408248   0.5 -0.408248)
```

Answer (score 2):

The basis for the eigenspace associated with an eigenvalue with geometric multiplicity 2 is not unique.  So it is not unexpected that two different libraries would return different bases.

I don't see anything wrong with the results computed by `numpy.linalg.eigh` for `matrix1`.  For example,

```
In [47]: E1, V1 = linalg.eigh(matrix1)
```

Verify that `E1` and `V1` satisfy the eigenvalue problem:

```
In [48]: np.allclose(matrix1 @ V1, V1 @ np.diag(E1))
Out[48]: True
```

Verify that the vectors in `V1` are orthonormal:

```
In [49]: np.allclose(V1.T @ V1, np.eye(len(matrix1)))
Out[49]: True
```